# AngularJS: Select not 2-way binding to model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am using a select to show Client names. A user should be able to select an existing client, which will then update the scope property:

**Controller**

*Initializing the "first pick".*

```
if($scope.clients.length > 0) $scope.existingClient = $scope.clients[0];
```

**View**

```
<select
    id='nm-existing-client-name'
    class='form-control  input-lg'
    ng-model='existingClient'
    ng-options="client.name for client in clients">
</select>
```

The scope property `existingClient` does not change when the select menu changes. If no value is initialized (controller line above is removed), the value of `existingClient` will stay undefined.

Attaching an `ng-change` will fire when a value changes, but the model itself will not update to the new value.

I am using *AngularJS v1.2.0-rc.3*.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Seems to work just fine if it's as simple as this [demo](http://jsbin.com/uNANUGA/1/). I'd say there is something else interfering with your code.

Comment: @Yoshi I figured as much. I'm not seeing any errors thrown in the console. I will do some deeper debugging now that I can see I am using ng-options/ng-model correctly.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

I think you are probably using a child scope and don't know it.  `ng-if`, `ng-repeat`, `ng-switch` and `ng-include` all create child scopes.  Values on your scope are inherited, but if you change the value in a child scope it sets a value on the child scope and leaves the inherited value unchanged on the parent.  Try using an object instead to hold your values and see if that fixes it.  Since you are only setting a property on an object and not a value directly on the scope it will use the parent scope's inherited object and update the value.

```
$scope.data = {
    existingClient: $scope.clients.length > 0 ? $scope.clients[0] : undefined
};
```

View:

```
<select ng-model="data.existingClient" 
        ng-options="client.name for client in clients">
</select>
```

You can use the [AngularJS Batarang extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en) in chrome to help debug your scopes.

Comment: I was using an `ng-if` in a higher block, which was creating a new scope. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I was having my select inside ng-include which created a new scope, your solution worked

Comment: `ng-switch` creates a new scope also, as does `ng-repeat`.

Comment: I added {{$id}} in different places in my template to see what was creating the new scope for me. Apparantly the AngularUI tab control creates a new scope for each tab.

Comment: Wow, this insight was incredibly helpful.  This is hard to diagnose when Angular implicitly creates a child scope.  Thank you.

Comment: If it helps anyone, I found my scope was nested two levels deep. Try ng-model="$parent.$parent.myVariable" to see. What is the advantage of creating a child scope?

Comment: It lets you have components and not have them worry about interfering with each other.  Like if you have a company page with a "name" field on the scope and an area displaying the employee of the month which might also have a "name" field.

Comment: What a big save! I didn't consider the problem about the scope. Thanks for this answer @JasonGoemaat.

Comment: Was banging my head on tons of solutions and this finally worked. Weird that the object needs to be a property $scope.xyz={abc: object}, not simply the object as a $scope.xyz=object, that saved the day, ++

Comment: Yeah, it's counter-intuitive the way the scope inheritance works.  When *reading* a value, it will look upwards on the scope hierarchy to find it (actually copies to the child when creating the scope I think).  But when *writing* a value it only sets the value on the current scope.  This allows you to track different variables called 'name' in a parent and child scopes, like a company might have a 'name' and 3 levels deeper in the component hierarchy might be an employee 'name' and not let the employee component overwrite the company name by accident when someone changes it.

Answer (score 1):

This is also a solution to keep parameters into your $scope object:

controller:

```
$scope.scope = $scope;
$scope.clients = [];
$scope.existingClient = $scope.clients.length > 0 ? $scope.clients[0] : undefined;
```

view:

```
<select ng-model="scope.existingClient" ng-options="client.name for client in clients"></select>
```

Comment: This didnt really help.

Comment: Do you realize that this answer is 3 years old? xD