# AngularJS - Typescript - Adding item to SelectList returns undefined

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have a page with on it a selectList

```
<div>
    <fieldset class="fieldset" style="width:500px">
        <legend>@CeMagResources.SelectArticle</legend>

        <div>
            <select data-ng-model="vm.newBon.CurrentArtikel" data-ng-options="artikel.omschrijving for artikel in vm.artikels track by artikel.id" style="width:100%"> </select>
        </div>
        <div data-ng-if="!vm.isNewArticleHidden" style="width:100%">
            <div ng-include src="'@Url.Action("AddArticle", "Artikel")'" ></div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

</div>
```

This page includes this

```
 <div>
        <fieldset class="fieldset">
            <legend>@CeMagResources.ArticleAdd <img style="vertical-align: central" alt="new" data-ng-click="vm.addArticle()" class="icon-new" src="@Links.Content.icons.add_png"></legend>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label class="ui-form ui-form-label">@CeMagResources.ArticleName:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" style="width: 150px" data-ng-model="vm.newBon.CurrentArtikel.Code" capitalize>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label class="ui-form ui-form-label">@CeMagResources.ArticleDescription:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" style="width: 150px" data-ng-model="vm.newBon.CurrentArtikel.Omschrijving" />

                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
```

In my .ts-file I have a functions where I add the article.

Here i send the article to the server, where it is added. So far so good.

```
 addArticle = () => { 
                this.bonSrv.addArticle(this.newBon.CurrentArtikel).success(this.setNewArticle);
                }
```

When i return from the angular-promise, i come into this function.
The article returned is the same as this.newBon.CurrentArtikel, only it has also an ID, what i need in the selectList.

```
setNewArticle = (artikel: IArtikel) => {
                this.artikels.push(artikel);
                this.newBon.CurrentArtikel = artikel;
                this.hideNewArticle();

            }
```

I already read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412410/angularjs-losing-scope-when-using-ng-include) that ng-include creates an child-scope and many solutions on the web suggest that i must use an 
[object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19408883/angularjs-select-not-2-way-binding-to-model) to bind it to. This i already do
Also other suggest that i must use [ng-options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26211573/angularjs-select-not-updating-when-ng-model-is-updated). This i also do.

When i debug in chrome, i see that the new article is pushed to the list and set as this.newBon.CurrentArticle()

Has anyone a idea why i get an undefined-option in my selectlist?

```
<select data-ng-model="vm.newBon.CurrentArtikel" data-ng-options="artikel.omschrijving for artikel in vm.artikels track by artikel.id" style="width:100%" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">
<option value="4" label="A2-Papier">A2-Papier</option>
<option value="3" label="A3-papier">A3-papier</option>
...
<option value="41" label="Zonnebril">Zonnebril</option>
<option value="undefined" label="undefined" selected="selected"></option>
</select>
```